# PATH settings not taking effect

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-7, registry, forever

So I have an node app that I run & maintain on a Windows 7 box, and all of a sudden i check in on it today and node, npm, forever, etc. are all not working. I look and see there were some Windows Security updates the last couple days but that's all I see, so not sure what happened here.

Trying to start my app up with 'forever -w app.js' results in 'forever' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

OK fine, i run 'node app.js' and that gives me 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command.  First thing i think of is to check my PATH and it's nearly empty (like it's been reset) npm folder is the only thing in there, but npm isn't working.

So I add "C:\Program Files\nodejs" to my path, reboot and still no good.

Tried re-installing Node (9.5), also tried upping to the latest ver (10.5) but neither worked.

Next after rolling back to node 9.5 I Manually execute SET PATH="C:\Program Files\nodejs";C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm;%PATH% to add both folders to the path and now node, npm, & forever all work fine... until I close the cmd prompt or reboot and it stops working again.

So i have it band-aided to work if i execute that every time i open cmd prompt... but anyone know why my PATH settings aren't taking effect on reboot? I tried searching and found a few tips like putting quotes around any PATH variable with a space in it, and changing the registry HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Environment PATH variable type from REG_SZ to REG_EXPAND_SZ but neither did the trick.

Comment: you can get the path of npm by using " npm config get prefix " and set the path to C:\Users\{yourName}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Comment: if you are using cordova ... you need to switch to win8.1 or 10 ... try to call cordova requirements  command

Comment: Thanks; not using cordova though, and everything was working until a few days ago so Win 7 should be fine, it's been running about 2 years on here.  'npm config get prefix' shows i am adding the correct npm path, so it's not an issue of using the wrong one, and as i mentioned adding it via command line works and everything will work for that cmd prompt session; it just won't save if i reboot or close the window.